Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context[...] for 60 seconds
I am getting this error on code that used to work'
Here is the full error:
Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xe163c8 to COM context 0xe16310 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations
And here is the code that caused it:
// XOR the values to find differing bits

uint diff = word1 ^ word2;
for (int bitPos = 0; bitPos < 32; bitPos++)
{
// Check if the bit at position `bitPos` differs between value1 and value2
if ((diff & (1U << bitPos)) != 0)
{
    // 1 -> 0 change (bit was 1 in value1 and 0 in value2)
    if ((word1 & (1U << bitPos)) != 0 && (word2 & (1U << bitPos)) == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            byte id = (byte)(selectedGroups[bitPos / 32] * 32 + (bitPos % 32));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sysmonData.Append(" " + "UNKNOWN_ID_0x" + bitPos.ToString("X2") + ", ");
        }
    }

    // 0 -> 1 change (bit was 0 in value1 and 1 in value2)
    if ((word1 & (1U << bitPos)) == 0 && (word2 & (1U << bitPos)) != 0)
    {

        try
        {
            byte id = (byte)(selectedGroups[bitPos / 32] * 32 + (bitPos % 32));
           
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            
        }
    }
}

I'm doing bit comparison between two hex dwords when bit changes occurs from 0 to 1
and 1 to 0, Capturing the bit position (explanation of above code)
I'm not sure why I'm getting above Error please anyone have an idea let me know

The error message probably means that you are "blocking" the UI thread. I.e. you are either doing a slow computation on the UI thread, or calling a method like Thread.Sleep() or task.Wait(). Or that you have an actual deadlock that might be caused by using locks incorrectly. But the posted code is just a bunch of bit manipulations, and is probably not related to the actual problem. So you should probably start by explaining what you are actually doing and what kind of application you are writing.
